# why won't my photos upload on the website?

Tags: image-upload

When I add a new product or review an older one as part of managing products, my photos do upload but don't show up in the thumbnail (even though thumbnail view is enabled). What am I missing?

Comment: please give me what to ask question

Comment: Your product image is not showing right?  If yes where the product images are not showing?

Comment: maybe you need to set the correct permissions, does the error show up?

Comment: command (execute it in Magento directory):> chmod -R 777 media/

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that could be causing this issue, but here's a few things for you to look into:

On the Product Information page in your admin backend, under 'Images', make sure the radio buttons have an image selected for 'Base Image', 'Small Image', 'Thumbnail', and that they aren't 'Excluded'

Make sure the product images exist under /media/catalog/product/ (relative to your document root)

Make sure the /media directory is in your Apache web server's group (usually 'www-data' or 'httpd'). Magento also needs to be able to write to this directory, so you can run this command to set those permissions:

**sudo chmod -R 775 /path/to/magento/media**

In **System->Configuration->General->Web**, make sure "Base Media URL" is correct under both "**Secure**" and "**Unsecure**"